# How to convert 'Future<String>' to the 'String'

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I am trying to show the firestore image, but the code I use it for requires Future, but in table obviously I can't use that. Can I somehow turn it into string? This is the place where link is taken:

```
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('erkekyuz');
// no need of the file extension, the name will do fine.
  var url = ref.getDownloadURL();
```

and where I invoke it:

```
Text(url), //THIS IS WHERE IT'S USED, only this doesn't work, if I remove this row, everything else works.
```

This is the full code. Feel free to use it, it works totally without image, if I remove this row it works perfectly, if you need only text data:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  runApp(MyApp());
 
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Basic Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'new Flutter App'),
    );
    
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  
  Widget _buildlistItem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot document) {
     final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('erkekyuz');
// no need of the file extension, the name will do fine.
  var url = ref.getDownloadURL();
    
    String mezunD;
    if (document.data()['mezunDurumu'] == false) {
      mezunD = "mezun değil";
    }
    if (document.data()['mezunDurumu'] == true) {
      mezunD = "mezun";
    }
    String yasString = (document.data()['yas']).toString();

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Table(
        border: TableBorder.all(),
        children: [
          TableRow(children: [
            Text("Ad Soyad:  "),
            Text(document.data()['adSoyad']),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text("Yaş:  "),
            Text(yasString),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text("Doğum Tarihi:  "),
            Text(document.data()['dogumTarihi']),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text("Mezun Durumu:  "),
            Text(mezunD),
          ]),
          TableRow(children: [
            Text("Fotoğraf:  "),
            Image(url), //THIS IS WHERE IT'S USED, only this doesn't work, if I remove this row, everything else works.
          ]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Öğrenci Durumu"),
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('tablolar').snapshots(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) return const Text('Loading...');
            return ListView.builder(
              itemExtent: 100.0,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.docs.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) =>
                  _buildlistItem(context, snapshot.data.docs[index]),
            );
          }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I just solved it myself!!! I made that field into a function like this:  `void showImage() async {
      final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('erkekyuz.png');
      // no need of the file extension, the name will do fine.
      url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
      
    }
    showImage(); //called here like this.`<br/>
then at the Image field like this:
`    Image.network(
                url,),`

Comment: Good to hear Crag .   I recommend posting that as a self-answer and accepting it, so that folks and the system both know your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just solved it myself!!! I made that field into a function like this:

```
void showImage() async {  
final ref = FirebaseStorage.instance.ref().child('erkekyuz.png');
url = await ref.getDownloadURL();
}
```

---

Then inside the Widget _buildlistItem field:

```
showImage(); //called here like this.
```

then at the Image field like this:

```
  Image.network( url,),
```